# rich:dataScroller does not work

Tags: java, jsf-2, richfaces

This is the scenario, I have a database table with bills payed and not payed by the customers. In the managed bean this is represented by a Map<Cliente, List<Carrito> where Cliente is every customer and List<Carrito> is the list of bills not payed.

I get this map by a query and at the same time I count how much Cliente are put in the map with his bills. This counter value is used to initialize an attribute (int[] page).

The map is displayed in one rich dataTable per Cliente. Each dataTable is paginated and in the footer of them I set,

```
<rich:dataScroller page="#{adminCarritoBean.page[current.index]}"/>
```

being current.index the index of a

```
<ui:repeat varStatus=”current”>
```

used for select every pair Cliente-List<Carrito>.

Now the issues. I get a ClassCastException every time a select a page in the dataTable. I have a sample with two Cliente one with three bills a the other one with six bills. Every table show five bills so when the paginated one is shown in second place I can't paginate, the footer is locked.

Here is the code,

```
<ui:repeat value="#{adminCarritoBean.clientes.entrySet().toArray()}"
    var="cliente" varStatus="current" id="repeat">
    <table style="border-collapse:collapse; border:1px solid black;">
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>
          <h:outputText value="#{cliente.key.nombre} #{cliente.key.apellido1} #{cliente.key.apellido2}" />
          </td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<c:set value="#{adminCarritoBean.selectedIds.get(cliente.key)}" var="mapIds"/>
<rich:dataTable id="crtoTable" value="#{cliente.value}"
        var="crto" iterationStatusVar="it" rows="5">
    <rich:column>
    <f:facet name="header">Referencia</f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{crto.referencia}" />
    </rich:column>
    <rich:column>
    <f:facet name="header">Fecha de Compra</f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{crto.fechaCompra}" />
    </rich:column>
    ----------------------------
        ----------------------------
    <rich:column>
    <f:facet name="header">Select</f:facet>
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{mapIds[crto.id]}" />
    </rich:column>
    <f:facet name="footer">
        <rich:dataScroller page="#{adminCarritoBean.page[current.index]}"/>
    </f:facet>
</rich:dataTable>
<br />
</ui:repeat>
```

The code for initialization int[] page is as follows,

```
if(count > 0) {
loadList = true;
if((null == page) || ((null != page) && (count < page.length))) {
    page = new int[count];
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        page[i] = 1;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by the "locked". Is it disabled? Make sure `<rich:dataScroller>` has a parent `form`.

Comment: When I say "locked" I am meaning the buttons with the two pages appears and the first page as default as well but clicking the page 2 the dataTable does not move to the second page.